# How to structure a Map from Json that has duplicate keys

Tags: android, json, dictionary, gson

Ok so I have this piece of JSON that I want to parse with Gson. I would like the Strings to be the values and the longs to be the keys.

> {"completed_questions":[["String",12345],...]}

The issue is the data type, when I try a `Map<String, Long>` it parses everything but gives me an error because of the duplicate String keys.

I tried to reverse it thinking Gson would know to switch them around but when I tried `Map<Long, String>` I got an error about not being able to parse my Strings as Longs.

To get it to work I created a swap map class that takes the Key and Value types and swaps them like so `public class SwapMap<K, V> implements Map<K, V>` however translating the swapped map actions like put/get/remove seem to be pretty difficult to make work.

What's the best way to parse this with Gson even though the strings aren't unique? (But the numbers are)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So what I did is just made a custom Gson Deserializer that mapped these values to a `LongSparseArray<String>`, which is the best way to go about it.

This is the relevant parts of the Deserializer:

```
for (JsonElement array : jsonObject.get("my_key").getAsJsonArray()) {
    if (array.getAsJsonArray().size() == 2) {
      String value = array.getAsJsonArray().get(VALUE).getAsString();
      long key = array.getAsJsonArray().get(KEY).getAsLong();
      progress.completedActivities.put(key, value);
    }
  }
```

Then I just added it to my Gson creator like so:

```
@Provides @Singleton Gson provideGson() {
return new GsonBuilder()
    .registerTypeAdapter(MyClass.class, new MyClass())
    .create();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

JSON doesn't allow identical keys on the same level in a json object.  It seems like you are trying to map a json array to a java map.

Based on the following data structure, you would need a list if you want to use the default conversion provided by Gson.

```
  {
  "completed_questions": [
    [
      "String",
      12345
    ],
    [
      "String",
      12345
    ]
  ]
}
```

Here is a quick implementation:

```
  private static void mapToObject() {
        String json = "{\"completed_questions\":[[\"String\",12345],[\"String\",123456]]}";

        Gson gson = new Gson();
        CompletedQuestions questions = gson.fromJson(json, CompletedQuestions.class);

        for (List<String> arr : questions.getCompleted_questions()) {
            for (String val : arr) {
                System.out.print(val + " ");
            }
            System.out.println();
        }

    }

    public static class CompletedQuestions {

        List<List<String>> completed_questions;

        public List<List<String>> getCompleted_questions() {
            return completed_questions;
        }
    }
```

This outputs:

```
String 12345 
String 123456
```

The thing to note is that I am using a list for mapping purposes which closely resembles the data model provided.

This will require you to do the conversion to long yourself.  But the way that json string looks.  It seems like you would need to operate on the indices.  If you have control over the json structure, I would recommending creating a better model.  Other wise you can do something like list.get(0) -> your key list.get(1) -> your value which is the `long` on the inner list.

Comment: Yea, so I was worried about casting and using list.indexOf(); for searching but this option still looks cleaner than my SwapMap class.